# Handle For loop for a number, a string, or a list in python

Tags: python, list

Is there a better way to write for loop if loop variable can be a number or string or a list?

For example an original code:

`foo(x)`
x takes a number ex: 7, or a string ex:'hello'.

To upgrade the code to take a list (or range() ) while backward compatible I check type first:

```
if type(x) != list and type(x) != range:
    x = [x]
for i in x:
    foo(i)
```

Wondering is there a better way or function to handle this scenario without checking type?

Comment: *without checking type* - but the code still needs some inferring of the type

Comment: The "better way" is to avoid that situation in the first place. Once you are in that situation, then this (or similar) approaches is really the only way. So, since it sounds like you are deciding to do this, then the best solution is just not to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you want to avoid checking for specific types. Instead,  check for *behavior*.

In this case, you likely want to check whether `x` is [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable), but also not a `str`.

```
from collections.abc import Iterable


if isinstance(x, Iterable) and not isinstance(x, str):
    it = x
else:
    it = (x,)

for i in it:
    foo(x)
```

Note that a class need not explicitly inherit from the `Iterable` ABC in order for the `isinstance` check to pass. Any class that follows the iterable protocol is considered a "virtual subclass" of `Iterable` for `isinstance` checks.

Answer (score 1):

```
if not isinstance(x, (list, range)):
    x = [x]
for i in x:
    foo(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if not any([isinstance(x, list), isinstance(x, range)]): ...
```

or

```
if not any([isinstance(x, type_) for type_ in (list, range)]): ...
```

or

```
if type(x) not in (list, range): ...
```

have some fun with this constructions :)